# CentOS VirtualBox guest only serves Apache test page to Windows 7 host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization, virtualbox

The title sums up the situation and here are the specifics:

- website on the guest box is configured correctly in Apache and responds fine in browser on that machine
- guest box is set to use bridged adapter mode for network
- I've made an entry in my Win7 host file with the IP and domain of the site which I have configured in Apache on the guest CentOS VM
- Apache on the guest box responds to a request from a browser on the host box, but with the Apache test page
- I've verified that the host box is indeed loading content from Apache on the guest box by stopping httpd
- I've run nmap on the guest box IP from the host box and port 80 is open

Stumped from here. Sure I'm missing something easy but running out of stuff to try. Ideas?

Comment: You'll need to show the Apache virtual host configuration, etc.

Comment: @cjc Found the issue in the vhost config and it was indeed a simple one. I wish I had a good excuse for missing it initially but I don't. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and it was indeed a simple one that I had overlooked before. The vhost was setup with the line

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Pretty obvious that that's not what we want if we're to access the site externally. So I changed it to

```
Allow from all
```

and no surprise that everything now works as expected.